# calculate age with textfield swift 4

Tags: swift

I wanna calculate someones age who ist typed his birthdate in a textfield.

```
 @IBAction func profilSettings(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    var a = self.dob.text
    var c = a!.components(separatedBy: "-")
    var y1 = c[2]
    let cal = NSCalendar? = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: .gregorian)
    let now = Date()
    let year = Calendar.components(.year, from: dob!, to: now, options: [])
    let age = (year!) - Int(y1)!
    self.myage.text = String(age)        
}
```

Errors:

> Cannot assign to immutable expression of type "NSCalendar?.Type"
>
> Ambigous references to member "components(_:from:)"

Comment: is this Query Solved ?

Answer (score 2):

Here you can use this code to get Age from a entered Date String

```
/// DOB String Entered
let dob : String = "05-31-1996"

/// Format Date
var myFormatte = DateFormatter()
myFormatte.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"

/// Convert DOB to new Date
var finalDate : Date = myFormatte.date(from: dob)!

/// Todays Date
let now = Date()
/// Calender
let calendar = Calendar.current

/// Get age Components
let ageComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: finalDate, to: now)
print("Age is \(ageComponents.year!)") /// Output 21
```

**Output Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- Use `Calendar` rather than `NSCalendar`

  ```
  let cal = Calendar:identifier: .gregorian)!
  ```
- The error occurs, because you use the type `Calendar` instead of the instance `cal` and the API of `Calendar` is `dateComponents(...`

  ```
  let year = cal.dateComponents([.year], from: dob!, to: now)
  ```

There are more issues:

- `dob` must be a `Date` instance, the birthday.
- The line `let age = (year!) - Int(y1)!` is wrong, the expected result is `let age = year.year!`